# PageSpeed Insights what to do with js.cookie.min in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, optimization, pagespeed

Google's PageSpeed Insights now let's you download the optimized js and image files. 
I have found a js.cookie.min file in the js folder of this package that I downloaded from the PageSpeed Insights page after I run the test, but I am quite confused of what to do with it?
I have a WordPress site, is there a plugin or some basic modifications method to use this file?
Or is it necessary, after all?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your site in Chrome
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and go to **network** tab
3. Refresh your page by hitting <kbd>F5</kbd>
4. Write the name of file in `filter` box (search box) on top right of opened window
5. Locate the file on your server
6. **Replace** the file with it via FTP